# Schur polynomials with zeros in an infinite geometric progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, schur-functions

Let $a_1,...,a_n\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}^\times$ be algebraic numbers, such that $\frac{a_i}{a_j}$ is not a root of unity for $i\neq j$. Furthermore, let $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $m>1$.

**Question:** Is there a homogeneous polynomial $P\in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}[X_1,...,X_n]$ in $n$ variables of some degree $k$, such that $P(a_1^{m^\ell},…,a_n^{m^\ell})=0$ (*edit:* where $P$ is a certian Schur polynomial) for all $\ell\in\mathbb{N}_0$?

*Edit:* Originally, I asked myself this question where  is a certain Schur polynomial. Since there are indeed examples of such polynomials in general (as suggested by user44191 in the comments below), I should add this assumption to my question.

Comment: Choose $\alpha_3 = \frac{\alpha_2^2}{\alpha_1}$; then $\alpha_1 \alpha_3 = \alpha_2^2$, so $\alpha_1^a \alpha_3^a = \alpha_2^{2a} = \left(\alpha_2^a\right)^2$ for any $a$, including $a = m^\ell$ for any $m, \ell$. So $P = X_1 X_3 - X_2^2$ should answer your question, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Would you like to tell us what a Schur polynomial is?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is necessary to fully define Schur polynomials. They can be defined by a semistandard Young tableux (you can find this in the Wikipedia entry of Schur polynomials, right at the beginning of the _Properties_ section). What seems to be relevant is that these polynomials are symmetric, though.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. I don't see an easy proof in general. Similar questions have been asked in Arithmetic Dynamics (look for dynamical analogues of Mordell-Lang). Clearly, the answer is no for $n=2$. For $n=3$, if you had such a situation then you would get infinitely many points on a fixed number field on the curves of the form $P(x_1^{m^k},x_2^{m^k},x_3^{m^k})=0$ (for any $k$) and these curves will have all components of genus at least two if $k$ is large enough, so Mordell-Faltings prevents this, so the answer is no for $n=3$ also. (BTW, I assume $m>1$ and I guess you do too).

Edit: The counterexample of user44191 is correct. What goes wrong with my proof? $x^ny^n = z^{2n}$ factors as $\prod_{\zeta^n =1} (xy -\zeta z^2)$. So my assertion that you get curves of higher genus is wrong. It's only wrong if $P$ is a binomial, though. In this case $P=0$ is a translate of a subgroup of the torus $\mathbb{G}_m^2$.

Comment: I can construct counterexamples with non-binomials, e.g. by adding binomials together (e.g. $x_1^n y_1^n - z_1^{2n} + x_2^n y_2^n - z_2^{2n}$); you still should get the torus subgroup, but it happens in more cases than binomials.

Comment: @user44191 Yes, but with more variables. I am only claiming stuff with $n=3$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Originally, I asked myself this question where $P$ is a certain Schur polynomial. But I was wondering, if this can be negated even in general.